# How to delete unused methods in a big function?

Tags: javascript

sorry it's a repost because apparently there's a difference between methods and functions, sorry.

for example in this [library](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js/) I only need two or three methods, I don't need the other 15, is there a way to delete some methods without breaking the others, I tried deleting them manually but the library breaks. I want to delete them because they take place and I just can't,personally I hate it. thanks

Comment: If you delete them and it breaks, then that means you need them. Why does it bother you so much? Once minified it's probably not going to add much size.

Comment: You could re-write the library or try to replicate yourself. But the best answer is normally just to let it be... Just let it be.

Comment: You need to get over your need to remove what you, personally, aren't using - - that's not how coding works. If the application can't work without the other functions, then obviously they are needed.

Comment: The other thing you could try is just copying the parts you think you need into your code. Make sure you have permission to do this though

Comment: The most informative way (better than guessing), is to run your code in a debugger while stepping through the library code. You will know exactly what is used and what you don't need. I am in concert with the others though. you are focused on the "wrong problem".

Comment: ok thanks a lot guys

Comment: If you're purely concerned about size,  minify make sure your server compresses it. The 5 minutes that will take will be better spent than spending more time re-inventing the wheel. The library is not that big to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Phix and ControlAltDel have said, it sounds like your approach is more the issue than the code itself.

I suggest you decide which bothers you more: writing your own mini-library in your codebase which gives you only the methods you need, or making peace with the fact that there may be some unused code in what you are building.

Javascript bloat is absolutely a thing, and I give you kudos for caring about trying to limit it. It is unfortunately somewhat inevitable as the complexity of your project grows.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm going with writing my own mini library